# Add Dynamic Plot Subtitles in Rshiny

Tags: shiny

**What I achieved so far**: I have a fully **reproducible** shiny app (using `iris` dataset) which makes dynamic plots (one does not know how many plots will output) based on one or more selected dropdown value(s) (`Species` in this case).

**My question**: I'd like to add a dynamic subtitle from a column called `new`. To elaborate, each `Species` has exactly two unique values (e.g., `a` and `b` for `Species = setosa`). Is there a way to add these unique values so that it could be integrated into the dynamic plots ?

**What I tried**:

```
df() %>% select(new) %>% distinct() %>% pull()
```

However, this does not produce the output I want.

[image]

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

species <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa")
vals1 <- rep(c("a", "b"), 25)
vals2 <- rep(c("c", "d"), 25)
vals3 <- rep(c("e", "f"), 25)
vals <- c(vals1, vals2, vals3)

iris <- iris %>% 
  mutate(new = vals)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("General Overview", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        uiOutput("species_dropdown"),
        DT::dataTableOutput("table1"),
        textOutput("text1"),
        uiOutput("plots")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$species_dropdown <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      "var1",
      "Species:",
      choices = species,
      options = pickerOptions(
        actionsBox = T,
        header = "Close",
        liveSearch = T
      ),
      multiple = T
    )
  })
  
  filtered_data <- reactive({
    map(input$var1, ~ iris %>% filter(Species == .x)) %>% set_names(input$var1) 
  })
  
  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(input$var1)
    
    plot_output_list <- lapply(input$var1, function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot_", i, sep = "")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })
    
    do.call(flowLayout, plot_output_list)
  })
  
  observeEvent(filtered_data(), {
    iwalk(filtered_data(), ~ {
      output[[paste0("plot_", .y)]] <<- renderPlot({
        ggplot(.x, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = .y, x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width") # how to make and integrate dynamic subtitles from output$text1 ?
      })
    })
  })
  
  df <- reactive({
    req(input$var1)
    
    iris %>% 
      filter(Species == input$var1)
  })
  
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df()
  })
  
  output$text1 <- renderText({
    df() %>% select(new) %>% distinct() %>% pull()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the information provided by `filtered_data` and inside the `walk` function, create during each iteration a variable called `subt` that will capture the unique values from `new` column.

```R
  observeEvent(filtered_data(), {
    iwalk(filtered_data(), ~ {
      subt <- pull(., new) %>%
        unique() %>%
        str_c(collapse = ",")
      subt <- paste("Unique values are:", subt)
      output[[paste0("plot_", .y)]] <<- renderPlot({
        ggplot(.x, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = .y, subtitle = subt, x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width") # how to make and integrate dynamic subtitles from output$text1 ?
      })
    })
  })
```

Full app:

```R
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)

species <- c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica")
iris %>% filter(Species == "setosa")
vals1 <- rep(c("a", "b"), 25)
vals2 <- rep(c("c", "d"), 25)
vals3 <- rep(c("e", "f"), 25)
vals <- c(vals1, vals2, vals3)

iris <- iris %>%
  mutate(new = vals)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "title"),
  sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("General Overview", tabName = "tab1", icon = icon("dashboard"))
    )
  ),
  body <- dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "tab1",
        uiOutput("species_dropdown"),
        DT::dataTableOutput("table1"),
        textOutput("text1"),
        uiOutput("plots")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$species_dropdown <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(
      "var1",
      "Species:",
      choices = species,
      options = pickerOptions(
        actionsBox = T,
        header = "Close",
        liveSearch = T
      ),
      multiple = T
    )
  })

  filtered_data <- reactive({
    map(input$var1, ~ iris %>% filter(Species == .x)) %>% set_names(input$var1)
  })

  output$plots <- renderUI({
    req(input$var1)

    plot_output_list <- lapply(input$var1, function(i) {
      plotname <- paste("plot_", i, sep = "")
      plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
    })

    do.call(flowLayout, plot_output_list)
  })

  observeEvent(filtered_data(), {
    iwalk(filtered_data(), ~ {
      subt <- pull(., new) %>%
        unique() %>%
        str_c(collapse = ",")
      subt <- paste("Unique values are:", subt)
      output[[paste0("plot_", .y)]] <<- renderPlot({
        ggplot(.x, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
          geom_point() +
          labs(title = .y, subtitle = subt, x = "Sepal Length", y = "Sepal Width") # how to make and integrate dynamic subtitles from output$text1 ?
      })
    })
  })

  df <- reactive({
    req(input$var1)

    iris %>%
      filter(Species == input$var1)
  })

  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    df()
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    df() %>%
      select(new) %>%
      unique() %>%
      pull()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```